# How do I get the counter of a google plus +1 button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus-one

I have added a google +1 button to a website, but I want to get it's counter so i can do some math over it. is it possible to enter the iframe created by the standard method of creating the +1 button or do I need to make some adjustment?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
<g:plusone></g:plusone>
```

I've tried this link:[1](http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/blog/google_plus_one_button_seo_count_api/) , but this is not very accurate

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you can access curl/file_get_contents/readfile/wget or some way to fetch an external URL, this is quite simple.

Load the following URL: `https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=URLENCODED_URI` (**UPDATED URL, see note below ***)

URLENCODED_URI is the site you wish to know the number of +1's for, e.g. http://www.google.com (http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com)

For example, fetch the URI `https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http://www.google.com/` (**UPDATED URI**) and locate the first occurance of `window.__SSR = {'c':  32414.0 ,'si'`. Preferably use regexp for this, but I'll leave the implementation to you and your chosen programming language (server side or client side).

The float number following `'c'` is the number of +1's the site have. For google.com this is 32,414. Don't worry about the float, you can safely convert it to an integer.

*** UPDATE:** The URL has been updated as the old URL started to 404. Remember, this is expected as this is an unofficial method. There exist no official method (yet).

Comment: Apparently it is a way to go. I'll give it a try and post the results here later.

Comment: would you mind telling me how did you figure this out, or where did you find this answer?

Comment: I inspected the network traffic caused by the plus button on a few sites (credits goes to the lovely WebKit Inspector in Safari and Chrome) and found out that they all behaved in a certain manner, and they all called a certain url which in turn returned html and javascript. I found that the javascript contained the number of +1's, regardless of wether the number of +1's was represented as 32k, 'hundreds' or 14.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction, I now have a cookie-free asynchronous call to get the google plus count to go along with my facebook, twitter, stumble upon and delicious calls.

Comment: This seems good, I was considering a solution like this, but I am having a problem do you think you could help, this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043558/google-plus-count-url

Comment: Use the URL https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoursite.com%2Fpath%2Fyour%2fcontent instead and follow the same steps.

Comment: @VinnyD, check my answer, which is client-side.

Answer (score 4):

Could you use a callback function to grab the value of the div that displays the count?

```
function count() {
    var count = $('#aggregateCount').html();
}

    <g:plusone callback="count()"></g:plusone>
```

I'm basing this off the [bubble annotation button](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/), I haven't tested it but something like this should work.

Comment: As far as I understand the callback attribute, it is only called once the user clicks the button.

Comment: ah, what about an onload then?

Comment: i cant seem to find that event, @barro32. The available events are all user interaction related.

Answer (score 2):

A pure client-side solution that works for me to get the Google Plus counter is as follows. It does not need an API key.

```
var url = "http://www.yoursite-to-be-counted.com";
var data = {
    "method":"pos.plusones.get",
    "id": url,
    "params":{
        "nolog":true,
        "id": url,
        "source":"widget",
        "userId":"@viewer",
        "groupId":"@self"
    },
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "key":"p",
    "apiVersion":"v1"
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://clients6.google.com/rpc",
    processData: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(r){
      setCount($(".google-plus-count"), r.result.metadata.globalCounts.count);
    }
  });

  var setCount = function($item, count) {
    if (count) {
      $item.text(count);
    }
  };
```

Then I have some html with

```
<div class="google-plus-count"></div>
```

Credits here goes to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28113687/914874) answer.