# Google Plus Count url

Tags: url, client-side, google-plus, google-plus-one

I'm trying to get the count of plus one's I have for google plus, I am checking to see if I have the count right with this

```
https://plusone.google.com/u/0/_/%2B1/fastbutton?count=true&url=MY_URL
```

I see that google plus rejects my URL (doesn't return 0 or anything)

I wanted to know if anyone can tell me if I have anything wrong in my url, I have these symbols in my url outside of letters and numbers

```
:
/
.
?
=
&
_
```

and my url is formatted like this

```
(protocol)://(server [such as www]).(domain)/(text).php?(text)=(text)&(text)=(digits)&(text)=(text)
```

Comment: i guess, you can try "escaping" the URL character so that things such as / are passed correctly to the google server...

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button

Answer (score 1):

Use the URL

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yoursite.com%2Fpath%2Fyour%2fcontent
```

instead and follow the solution found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button) (parse for `window.__SSR = {c:`)

Comment: still won't work for me (see the format of my url, maybe something in there would cause a problem)

Comment: I think I solved it, so how do you make a regex that does that (not comfortable enough with that) I'm able to load the url as a string now, but don't know how to extract the number, also to fix my problem I had to change & symbols to %26 and I sent GPlus_someotherstuff which google changes to googlePlus_someotherstuff so I need to use googlePlus_someotherstuff  in my request to google plus

Comment: im using php, (I could possibly use javascript instead)

Comment: right, make sure to url_encode the url you wish to examine number of plusones on. In php simply do `urlencode($url)`. A suitable regexp would be `preg_match('/window\.__SSR = {c: ([0-9]+)\.0/', $googleplusresonse, $matches);` which would result in `$matches[1]` holding the number of plusones.

Answer (score 0):

[I think you're looking for this.](http://shinraholdings.com/870/count-facebook-likes-twitter-links-and-google-pluses-with-php/#google-plus) It's ugly and Google clearly doesn't support it, but it still works.

```
function shinra_gplus_get_count( $url ) {
    $contents = file_get_contents( 
        'https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/fastbutton?url=' 
        . urlencode( $url ) 
    );

    preg_match( '/window\.__SSR = {c: ([\d]+)/', $contents, $matches );

    if( isset( $matches[0] ) ) 
        return (int) str_replace( 'window.__SSR = {c: ', '', $matches[0] );
    return 0;
}
```