# Getting google plus shares count with jquery

Tags: jquery, api, google-plus

I am trying to get Google plus shares count for a URL with Jquery.

```
url = 'www.abc.com/';
$.getJSON('https://clients6.google.com/rpc?key=AIzaSyBeAeOUk3BJs9ZXeohJX6Qt2zWXPQsRKRk'+'callback=?',
    {
       "method":"pos.plusones.get",
       "id":"p",
       "params":{
          "nolog":true,
          "id":'http://prince-antil.myshopify.com/',
          "source":"widget",
          "userId":"@viewer",
          "groupId":"@self"
       },
       "jsonrpc":"2.0",
       "key":"p",
       "apiVersion":"v1",         
    },
    function(data){          
    plusones = data.count;
    alert(data);
 });
```

But I am getting following error:

```
    {
 "error": {
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request",
  "data": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ]
 },
 "id": "p"
}
```

I have created an API but I am not sure about the way I have created it. Above error says "invalid key". I have cross checked the key but the key is correct. I don't know if there is something special need to configure in the APP area. I am new bie. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to separate your API key param from the callback param with an ampersand (&). However, this still will not work as the G+ API doesn't accept JSONP and rejects the callback param.

Answer (score 5):

Took some work but this solution did the trick. (Tested in Firefox and Chrome) No API Key required and no changes necessary. :)
Don't forget to include your jQuery file.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    /* Social Share: Google Plus JSON */
        var data = {
            "method":"pos.plusones.get",
            "id":"http://www.website_you_want_share_count_for.com",
            "params":{
                "nolog":true,
                "id":"http://www.website_you_want_share_count_for.com",
                "source":"widget",
                "userId":"@viewer",
                "groupId":"@self"
            },
            "jsonrpc":"2.0",
            "key":"p",
            "apiVersion":"v1"
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://clients6.google.com/rpc",
            processData: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success: function(r){
                $('#googleplus_page_share_count').text(format(r.result.metadata.globalCounts.count));
            }

        });
});

<p><span id="googleplus_page_share_count">256</span> Shares.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key `"p"` is certainly not correct.

You've given a more realistic key in the URL, but overwritten it with this dummy key.

Put it in the data array instead:

```
$.getJSON('https://clients6.google.com/rpc?callback=?',
    {
       "method":"pos.plusones.get",
       "id":"p",
       "params":{
          "nolog":true,
          "id":'http://prince-antil.myshopify.com/',
          "source":"widget",
          "userId":"@viewer",
          "groupId":"@self"
       },
       "jsonrpc":"2.0",
       "key":"AIzaSyBeAeOUk3BJs9ZXeohJX6Qt2zWXPQsRKRk",
       "apiVersion":"v1",         
    },
    function(data){          
       plusones = data.count;
       alert(data);
    }
);
```