# How to get Google +1 count for current page in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I want to get count of Google +1s for current web page ? I want to do this process in Javascript, then write number of shares or +1s to database. That's why, I need it. So, How can I do this process (getting count of +1s) in PHP ?

Comment: you might want to have a look at the accepted answere here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403553/how-do-i-get-the-counter-of-a-google-plus-1-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [official Google+ documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/) to know how to add the +1 Button with the count. It also has a code generator that generates the JavaScript code for you.

For getting these values via PHP (to write number of +1s in database), you can use cURL within PHP using the following code:

```
function get_plusones($url) {
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://clients6.google.com/rpc");
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '[{"method":"pos.plusones.get","id":"p","params":{"nolog":true,"id":"' . $url . '","source":"widget","userId":"@viewer","groupId":"@self"},"jsonrpc":"2.0","key":"p","apiVersion":"v1"}]');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
  $curl_results = curl_exec ($curl);
  curl_close ($curl);
  $json = json_decode($curl_results, true);
  return intval( $json[0]['result']['metadata']['globalCounts']['count'] );
}
```

Code referred from a [previous stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744589).

Comment: I've included the link that can generate the JavaScript code for you to show the count of +1s.
If your backend is in PHP, I don't think there is any way to use JavaScript to update the number in the database.